# Related list missing in Community until record is created

Tags: community

We have a community that exposes standard salesforce functionality (Salesforce tabs with visualforce).  We have noticed that related lists do not appear to community users until at least one related record has been created.  This seems very strange as once a related list record is created the community user can create new, edit, and delete this related list record.  Issue here is that users cannot create related records until one exists..  Anyone know why this is happening or how to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the master record being locked in an approval process.  Once the parent record was unlocked the related list appeared.